# How did Whatsapp app removed app's compatibility for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I have noticed using different applications that, even when you remove the iPad compatibility from xcode (see picture below)

[image: deployment info]

the app will still show that is compatible with iPad in the iTunes app page (see picture below):

[image: app compatibility]

Therefore, I am wondering, how did Whatsapp removed the iPad compatibility from it's app? (see image below):

[image: whatsapp compatibility]

Thank you

Comment: similar, outdated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767839/itunes-connect-excluding-ipad-from-supported-devices

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because WhatsApp does not work without telephony (the app requires the phone number) they did use `telephony` as [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html) value in their info-plist. This limits the app to devices that are designated as telephones. Which currently covers only iPhones, so the app won't work on iPads and iPods.

Generally you can't do that, Apple does not allow to arbitrary set `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. If your app really requires telephony support you can of course use the key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought the same but as far as I know you are able to make phone calls from iPad (if that has Sim Card installed). Am i right?

Comment: iPad does not support telephony, you can't make phone calls with them. iPads use cellular only for data.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I believe this is the answer then. :-)